# Cube functions: cubeset to retrieve column names instead of members

Tags: excel-formula, cube, cube-dimension

Hopefully someone can help me with the following.

In Excel, I want to retrieve column names from a certain dimension table, similarly to how you can retrieve members using the CUBESET function.

When I use CUBESET to retrieve members, the formula looks like this:

`=CUBESET("Data","[DimCustomer].[CustomerName].children","Cubeset CustomerName")`

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the **columns**, like CustomerName, from the dimension table. I was hoping something like this would work:

`=CUBESET("Data","[DimCustomer].children","Cubeset DimCustomer fields")`

However, this is not the case. Is this possible and does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.